# How does one accrue votes to undelete a question silently deleted due to lack of activity in order to edit and reactivate it?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, undelete, vote-to-undelete

My question [How far will Hayabusa-2 back off before the “bomb” goes off?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35307/12102) was silently deleted by the community bot for lack of activity and votes. I've revised it and would like to reactivate.

I voted to undelete but [then discovered](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54615533#54615533) that it doesn't appear in the review queue, so I'm forced to go to Space SE's chat room to beg for undelete votes.

**Questions:**

1. Is this the intended way for this to work, one has to appeal for undelete votes in chat rooms or perhaps by flagging for moderator assistance?
2. Was I notified of the deletion, or is my recollection correct that it happened without any notification to me?

**note:** I'm not requesting undelete votes or un-deletion here, I'm just trying to understand how the site works, thanks!

Comment: Chat? Why not meta?

Comment: This is answered in our FAQ on deleted posts, [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that), in the section *How can I undelete one of my posts?*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system does not send out notifications for questions being deleted, no.

If you want to get the question undeleted, you have a few options -

1. Go to meta. Explain that it was auto-deleted and explain that you've revised the question to improve it. See if you can find enough people to vote to reopen. It's also possible a mod will see the post and do it for you.
2. Flag the post. Custom flags can be cast on deleted posts - explain your request and see what the mods say.

I'd... go in that order, in particular. See what the community says, then if the mods don't see the meta post or if there aren't enough people to undelete, a mod can do it unilaterally.

You mention chat... that's really going to depend on the site. Many sites don't have active chat rooms and, even if they do, the people in chat may not be able to undelete posts. If the chat room is frequented by people who *can* undelete, it's an option for you but keep the room's rules in mind... if they ask you not to post there, respect that request.

If you're a regular in the room, you should have a good idea of whether that sort of thing is appropriate. If you're not, then feel free to ask - "Hey, do y'all mind if I make requests like this here?"

Comment: So the *intention* is for the bot to delete without the OP's knowledge by not generating a notification?

Comment: The bot deleting it is a red herring. We *never* notify people of deletions.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that you need good timing for undeletion as well. At best you have 7 days to get it above the roomba threshold.

Comment: @rene you mean before it gets re-deleted?

Comment: yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: @uhoh It's easy to miss (or forget about) but one of my favorite tools is the "recently deleted" list in the [10k tools](https://space.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last2days) and the "most undelete votes" list alongside it. It's a great place to review stuff that's been removed and see if there's valuable things that could be rescued. It's not a queue by any means but it is a place that high-rep users can find these posts.

Comment: @rene I... don't think I realized that it would get re-deleted if it didn't meet the minimums after seven days. :)

Comment: yes indeed, thank you!